# Homotopic product maps but components not homotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Say I have topological spaces (not necessarily distinct) $X, Y, A, B$ with $X\times Y$ and $A\times B$ the product spaces. Suppose we have continuous functions $f, g: X\to A$ and $f', g': Y\to B$. We know that $f\simeq g$ and $f'\simeq g'$ implies $f\times f'\simeq g\times g'$. However, does the converse hold? If $f\times f'\simeq g\times g'$, then is it necessarily the case that $f\simeq g$ and $f'\simeq g'$?

Comment: Just an idea: You have a homotopy $X\times Y\times [0,1]\to A\times B.$ Find a map $X\times [0,1]\to X\times Y\times [0,1]$ and a map $A\times B\to A$ to give a homotopy.

Comment: You might want to assume every space is question is non empty. Also, in general, if $h$ and $k$ are homotopic, then $f\circ h$ is homotopic to $f\circ k$

Apply this with the fact that $\pi_A \circ f\times f' = f \circ \pi_X$, we can obtain a homotopy $f \circ \pi_X$ to $g \circ \pi_X$. Given the spaces are non-empty, this might help, though I haven't worked out the details

Answer (score 1):

Yes if both $X, Y \ne \emptyset$.

Let $H : X \times Y \times I \to A \times B$ be a a homotopy such that $H_0 = f \times f'$ and $H_1 = g \times g'$, where $H_t = H(-,t)$.

Pick $y \in Y$ and define $i_Y : X \to X \times Y, i_y(x) = (x,y)$. Then
$$H^X = p_A \circ H \circ (i_y \times id_I) : X \times I \to Y$$
with projection $p_A : A \times B \to A$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

The proof of $f' \simeq g'$ is similar.